# Is it possible to Serialize to XML using the same format of the XSD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization

I have generated a Class from an XSD using XSD2Code.

I now need to deserialize a conformant XML file for this XSD into an object of this class.

I have tried a number of XML Serializers, but they seem to use their own XML format, thus I am unable to externally edit a conformant XML file for deserializing into an object.

Is it possible to Deserialize into an object while maintaining the original format ie one can generate an XML file which is conformant to the XSD, and not the serializer's specific XML format.

Many thanks in advance.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I have found XSD2Code does this.